# Autocomplete of parentheses in PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell, autocomplete, parentheses, powershell-5.0

Is there some option to let PowerShell automatically fill in the second parenthesis in the PowerShell ISE? I used to like this feature in Android Studio, but I've found nothing about it when it comes to PowerShell.
Just a quick note, I use PowerShell 5.1, but want to use 6 in the future.

Comment: [1] no, you cannot do that in the ISE unless, perhaps, one of the paid-for addons has that ability. [*grin*] ///// [2] the ISE is not going to work with ps6. there is a blog post about making ps7 work with the ISE, but i cannot find it right now.

Comment: Powershell_ISE has reached its end of developement. You should use VSCode if you want to benefit from new functions. VSCode together with the Powershell extension has the function you're looking for.

Comment: The ISE has an object model, which means you can make it do things that you want. VSCode has extensions/tools that do this, and settings (user, workspace, keybindings) you can configure to make it do more. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/object-model/purpose-of-the-windows-powershell-ise-scripting-object-model --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/object-model/the-ise-object-model-hierarchy --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/object-model/the-iseoptions-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable, but requires some fancy scripting.

Please see Keith Hill's article from 2013:

https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/psreadline-a-better-line-editing-experience-for-the-powershell-console/

Search for:
"# Insert matching quotes, move cursor to be in between the quotes"

This is specific to quotes, but the same technique could be applied with parenthesis.